# Split numbers separated by tab

Tags: python, list, split

i am a rookie in python
from this code

```
b=[]
a=[]

c=[1-1-1904  01:00:00,000000, 1-1-1905  02:00:00,000000, 1-1-1906  03:00:00,000000]

#with open('nt.txt') as csvfile:
   # data=csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=('\t'))
    index=0
    for line in data:
        if (index >= 0 and index <= 2):
            b.append(line[1])
            index += 1
        else:break
```

i get as below

```
3
['1-1-1904  01:00:00,000000', '1-1-1904  01:00:01,000000', '1-1-1904  01:00:02,000000']
```

i would like to split the date and timestamps and put them in new lists individually. I added a test as c just u can run
   how can i do that?

Comment: Your definition of `c` is illegal. Please fix it. Also, how are `c` and `data` related?

Comment: yes,true. my intention was to give u a sample as input. the .txt gets this out as output and puts it one row. but c i will remove c.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is :

```
A = ['1-1-1904  01:00:00,000000', '1-1-1904  01:00:01,000000', '1-1-1904  01:00:02,000000']
```

and you use the following code:

```
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []

for item in A:
    temp = item.split(',')
    list_3.append(temp[-1])
    temp1 = temp[0].split("  ")
    list_1.append(temp1[0])
    list_2.append(temp1[1])
print list_1
print list_2
print list_3
```

You would get this as output:

```
list_1 = ['1-1-1904', '1-1-1904', '1-1-1904']
list_2 = ['01:00:00', '01:00:01', '01:00:02']
list_3 = ['000000', '000000', '000000']
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: this information is useful. my intention was to split the date and timestamps. put date in list_1 and timestamps in list_2.